# Is it possible to have same height for container in li when text breaks in 2 lines with css?

Tags: html, css

For example - I have an ordered list `<ol>` with 7 `<li>` items in it and each one of them contains some `<div></div>` containers and one of them is `<div class="title"></div>`. And when resizing screen in one of the `<li>` items title container breaks and makes 2 lines. Is it possible to expand all other `<div class="title"></div>` that in all li items that container still matches in height? 
I mean using just css, without javascript

In pictures - Current result - 
[image]

Expected result - 
[image]

Thank you a lot for any advice! :)

Comment: Please provide your code or jsfiddle as well.

Comment: @JoykalInfotech Hey, sorry for late respond, here is fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/t7kmsqoe/2/ I want every container to match in height so in the end every `product-item` are in same height. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

able with grid.

```css
.box {
  width:360px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap:20px;
  grid-auto-rows:30px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
  padding:10px;
  
}

.price1, .price2, .price3 {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="text1">asdasd asdasda  sad as asd</div>
  <div class="text2">asdasd asd</div>
  <div class="text3"> asdasd asd </div>
  <div class="price1">$58.00</div>
  <div class="price2">$58.00</div>
  <div class="price3">$58.00</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code:

```js
var maxHeight = -1;
$('.product-item').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.product-item-brand').height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(this).find('.product-item-brand').height();
    }
});
$('.product-item-brand').height(maxHeight);

var maxHeight1 = -1;
$('.product-item').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.product-item-link').height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(this).find('.product-item-link').height();
    }
});
$('.product-item-link').height(maxHeight);

  
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
   var maxHeight = -1;
$('.product-item').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.product-item-brand').height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(this).find('.product-item-brand').height();
    }
});
$('.product-item-brand').height(maxHeight);

var maxHeight1 = -1;
$('.product-item').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.product-item-link').height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(this).find('.product-item-link').height();
    }
});
$('.product-item-link').height(maxHeight);
});
```

```css
       .product-items {
         list-style-type: none;
         display: flex;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
       }

       .product-item {
         max-width: 200px;
         max-height: 262px;
         text-align: center;
       }

       .product-item-name {
         border: 1px solid red;
         a {
           text-decoration: none;
         }
       }

       .product-item-link {
         -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
         display: -webkit-box;
         -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
         overflow: hidden;
         text-overflow: ellipsis;
       }

       .product-item-brand {
         line-height: 15px;
         border: 1px solid black;
       }

       .product-price {
         margin-top: 20px;
         line-height: 19px;
         border: 1px solid green;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="products list items product-items">
  <li class="product-item">
    <div class="product-item-info">
      <div class="product details product-item-details">
        <div class="product-item-brand">
          this one have brand name
        </div>
        <div class="product name product-item-name">
          <a class="product-item-link" href="#">long word goes here will break in 2 rows, qwerty 123456</a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price-block">
          <div class="product-price">
            $15
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="product-item">
    <div class="product-item-info">
      <div class="product details product-item-details">
        <div class="product-item-brand">
          this one also
        </div>
        <div class="product name product-item-name">
          <a class="product-item-link" href="#">long word goes here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price-block">
          <div class="product-price">
            $15
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="product-item">
    <div class="product-item-info">
      <div class="product details product-item-details">
        <div class="product-item-brand">
          next doesnt have, need to set empty space
        </div>
        <div class="product name product-item-name">
          <a class="product-item-link" href="#">long word goes here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price-block">
          <div class="product-price">
            $15
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="product-item">
    <div class="product-item-info">
      <div class="product details product-item-details">
        <div class="product-item-brand">

        </div>
        <div class="product name product-item-name">
          <a class="product-item-link" href="#">long word goes here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price-block">
          <div class="product-price">
            $15
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```